# yield in method without loop

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am studying ruamel.yaml API using source code and found [this strange pattern in code](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/0.17.10/tree/constructor.py#l1612):

```py
    def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        data = CommentedMap()
        data._yaml_set_line_col(node.start_mark.line, node.start_mark.column)
        yield data
        self.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
        self.set_collection_style(data, node)
```

which then makes it necessary to write code like this ([inspired by the code in another place](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/0.17.10/tree/constructor.py#l190))

```py
generator = yaml.constructor.construct_yaml_map(mapping_node)
# method does not run, only returns generator

data = next(generator)
# method executes until yield data (empty CommentedMap)

for _dummy in generator:
  # on first iteration method continues until end
  # no second iteration
  pass

# or alternative expression
#try:
#  next(generator)
#except StopIteration:
#  pass

# now data is filled
```

What could be the use of this `yield` in the middle of the method without any loop?

Comment: Looks like an awkward attempt at [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) written by someone who doesn't know about context managers.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This PyYAML code dates from about the same time that context managers were discussed for Python 2.5, and those certainly were not available (at that time) for all actively maintained Python versions. I was certainly aware of, and using, context managers when I derived the `ruamel.yaml` code from PyYAML, but I don't see how they could help solve the issue of supporting recursive construction with self reference, so I would be interested in a working example using context managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python allows you to create recursive data structures, and contrary to
many other streaming formats, YAML allows you to dump these

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(a=1)
data['b'] = data

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
&id001
a: 1
b: *id001
```

In this the `&id001` is an anchor in YAML speak, and it is referred to by `*id001`, called an alias.

I don't know of a way to create `data` in Python without using more than one statements. You need
the object (or its `id`) to be able to add it to itself. The YAML loader has as simimlar problem:
when it parses and constructs a composite (a mapping or a sequence), it gathers all the
children (key/value pairs resp. elements) and then constructs the composite. So when a composite
in YAML refers to itself (through an alias) the lookup for the anchor needs to provide a real, albeit
incomplete, constructed Python object (dict, list, and in case of a tagged object possibly an instance
of some class).

This is why the two-step process of creating composites is used: you make an empty object which
you hand back so if necessary a reference in the anchor/alias table can be made,
and then you fill it in, in the post `yield` part of the code.

Composites don't need to have an alias themselves in one of
their values or elements, but if they don't have an anchor they could
be constructed in a one step process. But this would lead to having
different constructors and the code calling `construct_yaml_map()` to
understand about these differently constructed objects. The problem
shifts, but doesn't go away, just like you can create the recursive
Python differently, but still need multiple statements.

BTW this is not `ruamel.yaml` specific. This code was, and AFAIK still is, in the PyYAML code
from which `ruamel.yaml` was derived.